# Split a datetime range in individual day slots e.g. access the number of minutes for each individual day present in a datetime range

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, date-range, moment-range

I have a start date object and an end date object in javascript e.g.

```
var startDate = moment("2019-04-22T09:20:00+05:00");
var endtDate = moment("2019-04-25T11:00:00+05:00");
```

now I want to have an output like this

```
[880,1440,660] //array for the numbers of minutes for each day present in the given range
```

I have tried something using moment range module but still in vain

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: can you explain your output that how you calculate that?

Comment: at the index zero: 14 hours and 40 minutes are remaining till the start of the next day; convert it into minutes you will have 880

Comment: from where this 600 comes

Comment: on 25th date till 11:00 am 600 minutes are passed

Comment: its 660 i think

Comment: no as 11th hour is not passed yet

Comment: it is eleven that means 11 hours are passed

Comment: I am really sorry you are right I will update my question thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192213/discussion-between-saim-abdullah-and-syed-mehtab-hassan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```js
var startDate = moment("2019-04-22T09:20:00+05:00");
var endDate = moment("2019-04-25T11:00:00+05:00");

var duration = moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate));
var days = Math.round(duration.asDays());


var start,end;
var minutes = [];

for(i = 0; i<=days; i++){
  if(i == 0){
    start = startDate;
    end = moment(startDate).endOf("day").utcOffset("+05:00");
  }else if(i == days){
    start = moment(endDate).startOf('day').utcOffset("+05:00");
    end = endDate;
  } else {
    start = moment(startDate).add('days', i).startOf('day').utcOffset("+05:00");
    end = moment(startDate).add('days', i).endOf('day').utcOffset("+05:00");
  }
  
  var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
  var min = duration.asMinutes();

  minutes.push(Math.round(min))
}

console.log(minutes)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I will update your code to support the local timezone of the user

Comment: if you provide different time with the same dates then the output is wrong but I got your point so I am accepting your solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this code simply calculate minutes for start and end date and push 1440 minutes for between dates by calculating days between two dates

```js
function getMinutes(dt1, dt2) {
  minuteArray = [];

  // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
  var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 

  startHours = (24 - dt1.getHours())
  if (dt1.getMinutes() > 0) {
    startHours--;
  }

  // Calculate Minutes for start date
  startDayMin = startHours * 60 + (60 - dt1.getMinutes());

  minuteArray.push(startDayMin);
  var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((dt1.getTime() - dt2.getTime()) / (oneDay))) - 1; //Calculate number of days

  for (i = 0; i < diffDays; i++) {
   
    //Push minutes for number of days
    minuteArray.push(1440);

  }

 if (diffDays >= 0){
   // Calculate Minutes for end date
    endDayMin = (dt2.getHours()* 60) + dt2.getMinutes();

    minuteArray.push(endDayMin)
}
  return minuteArray;
}



var startDate = new Date("2019-04-22T09:20:00+05:00");
var endtDate = new Date("2019-04-25T11:00:00+05:00");
console.log(getMinutes(startDate, endtDate));
```

Comment: try to provide the same date with different times, the output returns an array of length two .